# Django Debug Toolbar throwing 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: django, django-debug-toolbar

I am using Django==1.4.5, Python==2.7.5 and trying to put a profiler like django-debug-toolbar.
I have followed the documentation and applied the following settings in my local settings :-

if DEBUG:
    INTERNAL_IPS = ('127.0.0.1',)
    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES += (
        'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    )

```
INSTALLED_APPS += (
    'debug_toolbar',
)

DEBUG_TOOLBAR_PATCH_SETTINGS = False
DEBUG_TOOLBAR_PANELS = [
    'debug_toolbar.panels.versions.VersionsPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.timer.TimerPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.settings.SettingsPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.headers.HeadersPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.request.RequestPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.sql.SQLPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.staticfiles.StaticFilesPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.templates.TemplatesPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.cache.CachePanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.signals.SignalsPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.logging.LoggingPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.redirects.RedirectsPanel',
]

DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
    'INTERCEPT_REDIRECTS': False,
}
```

I am getting this error 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'

```
Traceback:
File "/Users/nikhilverma/workspace/BHANE/pyenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  136.                     response = response.render()
File "/Users/nikhilverma/workspace/BHANE/pyenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  104.             self._set_content(self.rendered_content)
File "/Users/nikhilverma/workspace/BHANE/pyenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
  81.         content = template.render(context)
File "/Users/nikhilverma/workspace/BHANE/pyenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  140.             return self._render(context)
File "/Users/nikhilverma/workspace/BHANE/pyenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/utils.py" in instrumented_test_render
  61.     template_rendered.send(sender=self, template=self, context=context)
File "/Users/nikhilverma/workspace/BHANE/pyenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py" in send
  172.             response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
File "/Users/nikhilverma/workspace/BHANE/pyenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/debug_toolbar/panels/templates/panel.py" in _store_template_info
  114.                             value.model._meta.app_label, value.model.__name__)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Please advice